# QGIS 2.2 problem, loading layer into road graph

Tags: qgis, network

I have the road graph plugin installed, but when I try to configure it with the Settings dialogue, no layer names appear in the Layers field. I have tried various shapefiles, but the Settings dialogue doesn't see any of them. Anyone else seen this ? Thanks.

---

Addition:
I am having the same problem. A few more details regarding my experience of the issue, since not too many are provided above:

-Road Graph plugin version 0.1 with QGIS 2.2.0 32-bit via OSGeo4W install on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine. Tried same software versions on another Win7-64 machine (thinking maybe some setting was tweaked wrong). No difference. I have tried shapefile and spatialite line layers of topologically sound street networks. Tried having just one layer at a time loaded as well as multiple, with no change. Made sure CRS for layer and project were matched and that 'on the fly projection' was disabled. Also de/re activated plugin.

Under Vector>Road Graph>Settings all 3 dropdown menus under the Transportation Layer tab are grayed out/inaccessible with no options shown. All other settings in this dialogue are accessible.

Clicking on the canvas to choose Start and Stop points registers coordinates and shows selected points on the canvas. When 'Calculate' is attempted, "Plugin isn't configured" error (not surprising since layer couldn't be chosen).

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug with 2.2

I tried with 2.2 and reproduced your errors.

Then tried it with 2.4 with no errors.