# Removing pseudo-nodes with QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I've been struggling for a while now with pseudo-nodes.

Is there a tool that removes them automatically?

I have 1400 pseudo-nodes to correct and I'm wondering if there is a way to automate the process. I searched and found something about sextante plugin but that one is deprecated. 
I tried to dissolve everything and then snap them at intersections with v.clean but topology check still gives me 1400 errors of pseudo nodes after dissolving.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [v.generalize](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.generalize.html) tool from GRASS. It offers many algorithms that can help you to simplify your line network and remove pseudo nodes. Try to test them and see which one can give you the best result for your case. The help above provides explanation about each algorithm which can help you to decide which algorithm is more suitable for you.

You can find v.generalize tool under `Processing toolbox -> GRASS -> Vector -> v.generalize`

[image]

Comment: v.generalize will remove point using different conditions depending on the algorithm. It won't do anything with pseudo nodes.  Here is an answer to the question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112985/remove-pseudo-nodes-in-qgis/252228